# Controller does not change value of fullName

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){


  $scope.fullName = 'Test'
})
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController " ng-init="fullName='Khanh'">



 <p>Full name is {{fullName}}</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

1. First, I created an application varible fullName using ng-init.
2. I use controller myController to change the application variable (fullname)
3. I expected that the result is

Full name is Test

but it is

Full name is Khanh

Where I am wrong?

Comment: you are wrong about what you expect. It is the expected that fullName is Khanh because in Angular first JavaScript loads and initializes your objects etc. Than, ng-init called and changes your $scope object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your variables just when your controller is called, but if you really want to, you can create a function that will be called by your ng-init like:

```
<script>
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){

  $scope.fullName = 'Test'

  $scope.init = function(name){
    $scope.fullName = name;
  }
});
</script>
```

And then call this in your ng-init:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController " ng-init="init('Khanh')">
```

The sequence in which the code is executed is as follows:

- The controller is initialized when ng-controller is called (so all the fields in the controllers root scope will be set)
- After the controller is initialized, in this case, ng-init is called, and the value of fullName will be overwritten

It basically comes back to thinking about these kind of things in a logical way: how could you set the value of a field is it yet has to be declared (and initialized)? It can't, and thus, the field has to first be initialized before it can be used like so.

Comment: How does this explain why his expectations weren't met?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-init` is run after your controller is initialized, so it has access to its variables (and can override them).

[As per the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), you are using `ng-init` wrong:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.